# 403 Forbidden resposnse from a GET request to http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/news/6277112

Tags: espn

I have problem with the ESPN API:

I have an API key, and sent a query to the address http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/news/1581816?region=GB, which included my API key in the parameters.

I received 403 forbidden response: with this JSON 
{
  "status": "error",
  "code": 403,
  "message" : "Account Inactive"
}

I am looking at http://developer.espn.com/docs/headlines#using-the-api and at the last line it says that i can make a GET request to this url and it should work, but it doesn't.

How can I receive a valid response from the ESPN servers?

Comment: You dont have to include your ket, but can you show how you included it on ur get?

Comment: Did they require an email activations? You should check to make sure your developer account is in good standing.

Answer (score 1):

I just test it and it works fine.  That means your key is invalid, or you are not including it.  Replace  below and it will work.

```
http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/news/1581816?region=GB&apikey=<yourKey>
```

--

```
{
    timestamp: "2013-10-13T15:33:49Z",
    resultsOffset: 0,
    status: "success",
    resultsLimit: 10,
    resultsCount: 1,
    headlines: [
    { ... }
    ]
 }
```

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you very much for the quick response, it helped me. And do you know how i can get the full text of the article. In this link: http://developer.espn.com/docs/headlines#using-the-api it says: GET http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/news/6277112 Full text for a specific story.

Comment: And do you know how i can get the full text of the article. In this link: http://developer.espn.com/docs/headlines#using-the-api it says: GET http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/news/6277112 Full text for a specific story, but in the returned JSON response doesn't have a such a property to include the full text of the story. Thank you.